# Proxy con usuario y contraseña corporativo

Tags: nodejs, typescript, npm, angular8

me dirijo a ustedes con el fin de establecer como puedo crear un proyecto de angular si tengo internet limitado con proxy corporativo, el cual tiene usuario y contraseña.

Logre instalar Angular y TypeScript con la siguiente configuración:

```
/* Configuración de proxy */
npm set http://usuario:contraseña@proxy:puerto
/* Instalación de Angular */
npm install -g @angular/cli --without-ssl --insecure
/* Instalación de TypeScript */
npm install -g typescript --without-ssl --insecure
```

Pero si agrego sin ssl e inseguro me sale este error:

```
ng new aprendiendo-angular --style=scss --without-ssl --insecure
Unknown option: '--without-ssl'
Unknown option: '--insecure'
```

Al hacerlo normal sale lo siguiente:

```
ng new aprendiendo-angular --style=scss
```

1. Se queda en este punto por aproximadamente unos 30 minutos.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Luego de el tiempo de espera sale el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.22.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MiSusuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-10T19_30_36_426Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

Answer (score 2):

yo tuve un problema parecido y al final yo resolví con lo siguiente:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

Me tocó hablar con los de sistemas para que me proporcionaran los datos, pero te dejo un link que encontré por si te sirve.
https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió perfectamente.